# countif (with multiple column range) in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do this 2 simple excel functions in python but is very hard!
I'm a newbie in python...

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSMTe.png)

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance, imack.

Comment: please add what exactly these 2 functions do instead of showing it in the excel equation.

Comment: @TamilSelvan COUNTIF synthax: `=COUNTIF(Where do you want to look?, What do you want to look for?)` e.g. `=COUNTIF(A2:A5,"foo")` (`A2:A5` means in between the A2 and A5 cells, inclusive)

Comment: @TamilSelvan I have a dataframe and I want to create a new column that count how may time a value compare in two columns. In two columns in the range from row 0 to the considered row.

Comment: @Vianpyro Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: If you're using pandas please add that tag.

Comment: Kindly share reproducible data, not pics, with expected output

Comment: @Barmar ah ok thanks!

Comment: @sammywemmy yeah, I mistakenly assumed that with an excel image it was quite intuitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the closest I could do for now, it is not perfect but maybe you will find a way to improve it :)

```py
table = [
    ["a", "b"],
    ["b", "c"],
    ["c", "d"],
    ["b", "c"],
    ["c", "a"],
    ["a", "c"],
    ["c", "a"],
    ["c", "b"],
    ["a", "c"],
    ["c", "b"],
]

def countif(table, condition):
    count = 0
    for row in table:
        for col in row:
            if condition(col):
                count += 1
    return count

for index, element in enumerate(table):
    print(*element, countif(table[:index], lambda x: x == table[index][0]))
```

Result:

```
a b 0
b c 1
c d 1
b c 2
c a 3
a c 2
c a 5
c b 6
a c 4
c b 8
```

Comment: Great! Thanks Vianpyro... works perfectly but it's very slow :-(